# Traduction du réglage ajusté à « twelve o'clock » par analogie ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Un professionnel prépare un appareil pour fins de calibration (voir par exemple [ici](https://youtu.be/J31nVC0ms0w?t=7433) entre 2:04:00 et 2:04:20) et je comprends quelque chose comme :

> We'll turn the chicken head dial on the bottom left (of the device) to
>   (a) twelve o'clock (position).

Évidemment il ne s'agit pas d'une horloge et il n'y a pas d'indication « 12:00 » sur le réglage, on fait référence à une position par analogie avec le cadran/l'heure...

Préfère-t-on une [traduction](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/oclock/598543) avec une référence à l'heure et si oui, pourquoi et lequel de « 12:00 » ou de « midi » est le plus usuel, ou autrement comment traduirait-on vu le contexte ?

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais aussi bien

> Positionné à 12 heures.

que

> Positionné à mi-course. (Qui a l'avantage de pouvoir être utilisé avec un potentiomètre rectiligne.)

Comment: @0ne1: J'en vois bien un sous la réponse de mouviciel, mais l'autre ?

Answer (score 2):

Je ne comprends pas *twelve o'clock (position)*.

- Est-ce la position sommitale, comme sur un cadran d'horloge?
- Est-ce la position médiane, comme *midi*, le milieu du jour?

Les deux sont parfois distinctes, par exemple lorsque le zéro est tout en bas et que le potentiomètre a une course à trois-quarts de tour.

Les termes courants pour des positions grossières sont:

- **en butée, à gauche ou à droite**,
- **au minimum, au maximum**,
- **à mi-course**

Comment: +1 pour les expressions suggérées. Pour ton questionnement initial, la *clock position* est à interpréter dans le plan horizontal. Si on fait référence au plan vertical alors il faut être explicite et préciser l'heure suivie de *low* ou de *high*. Ta *position sommitale* devenant alors *12 O'clock high*

Comment: Dans le vidéo, la radio est couchée sur le côté. Dans un cas (phasing), c'est gradué de 0 à 10 sur 180 degrés et le réglage est au milieu, ce qui serait la verticale. Je t'invite à jeter un coup d’œil...

Answer (score 2):

Si on fait référence à une position angulaire par le moyen d'une locution horaire alors on utilise ce que l'anglais appelle *clock position* dont la paternité appartient aux aviateurs.

Dans cette *table de transcodage*, l'anglais va de 1 à 12 et dira donc ***twelve*** pour... pile en face.
Le Français va lui de 1 à 11 et dit ***MIDI*** pour ce qui se trouve droit devant!

Noter tout de même que cette information, pour être utile, est toujours nécessairement **relative à celui qui la reçoit!**. (et non relative à l'objet situé dans la direction)
Si il m'est impossible de présumer de la position de l'utilisateur par rapport à l'objet concerné... ce qui me semble nécessairement le cas dans l'exemple pris par l'OP... utiliser une position horaire me semble pour le moins hasardeux.

Cf les contributions de @Toto et @mouviciel pour des représentations plus recommandables.